# Organisation Sort Order

Tags: ckan

In CKAN 2.6.3 (and earlier), when you go to the organisations page, the default sort order is by Title (=end of the URL string).  In CKAN 2.7.2 which we are just upgrading too, the default sort order is by Name (which matches the drop down sort order choices).

Is it possible to retain/specify the sort by Title as default and/or add Sort by Title as an option in the drop down.  Whilst sorting by name is intuitively and functionally useful, in our use case we have some organisations which are bigger/more commonly used compared to others, so we have been able to retain them near the top of our list of organisations sorted by Title (default in 2.6.3) by editing the URL distinct from the Name e.g. put aa at front of url it comes to the top, put zz at front it goes to the end. By doing this for just a few organisations we can have effectively sort by name (title=name) but make commonly used ones easily accessbile at the top of the listing.

Thanks